# Kucoin C# issue with signature

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write bot to Kucoin API, but has fail with create signature.

```
var input = nonce;
var stringToSign = "/user/info/"+input+"/";
byte[] secretkeyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(SecretKey);
byte[] inputBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSign);
using (var hmac = new HMACSHA256(secretkeyBytes))
{
byte[] hashValue = hmac.ComputeHash(inputBytes);
return BitConverter.ToString(hashValue).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
}
```

But all times get error:

> {"code":"UNAUTH","msg":"Signature verification
>   failed","success":false,"timestamp":1}

On the official site we have such example

```
String strForSign = endpoint + "/" + nonce +"/" + queryString;  

//Make a base64 encoding of the completed string
String signatureStr = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(strForSign.getBytes("UTF-8"));

Mac sha256_HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(secret.getBytes("UTF-8"), "HmacSHA256");
sha256_HMAC.init(secretKeySpec);

//KC-API-SIGNATURE in header
String signatureResult =  Hex.encodeHexString(sha256_HMAC.doFinal(signatureStr.getBytes("UTF-8")));
```

Whats wrong in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing out the base64-encoding step for the input data. You need something like:

```
// String interpolation just to be simpler; no need for input variable either
var stringToSign = $"/user/info/{nonce}/";

// This is the step you were missing
var signatureString = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSign));

byte[] secretKeyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(SecretKey);
byte[] inputBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(signatureString);
using (var hmac = new HMACSHA256(secretKeyBytes))
{
    byte[] hashValue = hmac.ComputeHash(inputBytes);
    return BitConverter.ToString(hashValue).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
}
```

Comment: Trying this, but have the same error

var stringToSign = "/user/info/"+input+"/";
var signatureString = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSign));
byte[] secretKeyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secretKey);
byte[] inputBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(signatureString);
using (var hmac = new HMACSHA256(secretKeyBytes))
{
    byte[] hashValue = hmac.ComputeHash(inputBytes);
    return BitConverter.ToString(hashValue).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
}

Comment: @Zimsan: Putting a lot of code in a comment really doesn't end up being readable, but if it's exactly the same code as I've provided, there's no obvious reason why it would be wrong. Are you able to try the Java code with the same inputs?

Comment: Yeah, it same. I can try, but for this project I must use only c# or js (not node js)

Comment: It's working!!! Thanks, find issue in parameters and it's working with your code)

Comment: @Zimsan: Phew - I'm very glad, otherwise I'd have had no idea where to go next :)

Comment: I'd failed to convert it to lower case.
This worked great for me. Thanks!

Comment: It's UTF8 not UTF

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to post my code, it works and contains correct params because Zimsan's code contains small errors with parameters.

```
    public KuCoin_Balance GetAccountBalance()
    {
        KuCoin_Balance tmpBalance = new KuCoin_Balance();
        string domain = "https://api.kucoin.com";
        string endpoint = "/v1/user/info";
        string signatureResult = "";
        string SecretKey = apiSecret;
        long nonce = GetNonce();

        var stringToSign = $"/v1/user/info/{nonce}/";

        var signatureString = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSign));

        byte[] secretKeyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(SecretKey);
        byte[] inputBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(signatureString);
        using (var hmac = new HMACSHA256(secretKeyBytes))
        {
            byte[] hashValue = hmac.ComputeHash(inputBytes);
            signatureResult = BitConverter.ToString(hashValue).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
        }

        KuCoin_Response Resp = new KuCoin_Response();
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(domain + endpoint);
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.Headers["KC-API-KEY"] = apiKey;
        request.Headers["KC-API-NONCE"] = nonce.ToString();
        request.Headers["KC-API-SIGNATURE"] = signatureResult; // apiSecret;
        HttpWebResponse response = null;

        try
        {
            response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                if (responseStream != null)
                {
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                    {
                        Resp.StatusCode = "1";
                        Resp.StatusDescription = "Success";
                        Resp.ResponseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        //return Resp;
                    }//End of StreamReader
                }
            }// End of using ResponseStream
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Resp.StatusCode = "-1";
            Resp.StatusDescription = "Error";
            Resp.ResponseString = ex.Message.ToString() + "      " + response.StatusDescription;
            //return Resp;
        }
        return tmpBalance;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the solutions that I found but nothing works for me, so I tried to encrypt the sign this way and it works fine:

```
public void SendSignHeader()
{
    var method = HttpMethod.Get;
    var endopoint = "/api/v1/accounts";
    var body = new SortedDictionary<string, object>();
    long time = DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
    string Secret = "Your secret";

    var signature = GetSignature(method, endopoint, time, Secret, body);
    request.AddHeader("KC-API-SIGN", signature);
}


public string GetSignature(HttpMethod method, string endpoint, long nonce, string apiSecret, SortedDictionary<string, object> body = null)
            {
                var timestamp = nonce.ToString();
                var callMethod = method.ToString().ToUpper();
                var jsonedBody = body != null && body.Count > 0
                    ? JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body)
                    : string.Empty;`enter code here`
                var sigString = $"{nonce}{callMethod}{endpoint}{jsonedBody}";
                var signature = HmacSha256(sigString, apiSecret);
                return signature;
            }

public string HmacSha256(string message, string secret)
        {
            var encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
            var msgBytes = encoding.GetBytes(message);
            var secretBytes = encoding.GetBytes(secret);
            var hmac = new HMACSHA256(secretBytes);

            var hash = hmac.ComputeHash(msgBytes);

            return Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
        }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).